# Pascal GraphAbc, Когда я пишу 1, то две клетки закрашиваются

Tags: pascal

```
uses GraphABC;
var a,b: integer;
begin
    SetWindowSize(500, 500); 
    SetPenWidth(3);

    Rectangle(50,50,100,100);
    Rectangle(100,50,150,100);

    read (a);

    If a=1 then
    setbrushcolor(clBlue);
    Rectangle(50,50,100,100);

    If a=2 then
    setbrushcolor(clBlue);
    Rectangle(100,50,150,100);
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uses GraphABC;
var a,b: integer;
begin
    SetWindowSize(500, 500); 
    SetPenWidth(3);

    Rectangle(50,50,100,100);
    Rectangle(100,50,150,100);

    read (a);

    setbrushcolor(clBlue);

    If a=1 then
    Rectangle(50,50,100,100);

    If a=2 then
    Rectangle(100,50,150,100);
end.
```

Я понял

Answer (score 2):

если несколько операторов в if то наверное надо использовать begin .. end ? Похоже что у Вас прямоугольники рисуются независимо от условия if